# Most Efficient Way to Create a Game Level? (LibGDX)

Tags: java, android, arraylist, libgdx, tile

I am making a platformer-like game (not exactly a platformer; it's vertical scrolling), but the level loading should be similar. So far I have come across two ways to create a game level.

1. Using Tile Maps. Basically, you use some tiles to create your level in a Tiled Map Editor such as [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/), and then you use that as your level.
2. Using an ArrayList and store all the GameObjects (bricks, spikes, etc...). All of the objects and their positions would be stored in a text file and then accessed and placed into the array at runtime using StringTokenizer and a loop.

It seems to me that using the Tiled Map is easier and more convenient. Are there any disadvantages to using Tiled Maps and/or advantages to using the ArrayList method? Or is there another method that is even better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in your question : Tiled Map is easier and more convenient, text files are harder and less convenient then.

Instead of use text files with custom parsing, why not use standard well suited format like XML or JSON. Goos parser already exists for these formats.

If your question is about performances, don't worry, tiled is XML format and if you experiment performance issues in the futur you could pre-process your tiled maps to generate an optimized format for your game.

Answer (score 1):

Tile Maps might be easy to use once you learn it, but learning it might not necessarily be easy.  Here's the wiki to be sure:

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Tile-maps

If you think your game is simple enough that you can get it done with an `ArrayList` and `StringTokenizer`, I say why not.

However, say your game becomes more complex down the road.  You may be wishing you went for Tile Maps to help you manage that complexity.